# For an image or sequence, what is the properties transformers use?

Tags: conv-neural-network, transformer-model, self-attention

Today my teacher ask me a question: he said the CNN is use the translation invariance of the images or matrixs. So what is the properties Transformer uses ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main properties of transformers that makes them so appealing compared to convolutions:

1. A transformer is *permutation* equivariant. This makes transformers very useful for set predictions. For sequences and images where order does matter, positional encoding/embedding are used.
2. The receptive field of a transformer is the *entire* input (!) as opposed to the very limited receptive field of a convolution layer.

See sec. 3 and fig. 3 in:
*Shir Amir, Yossi Gandelsman, Shai Bagon and Tali Dekel* [**Deep ViT Features as Dense Visual Descriptors**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.05814.pdf) (arXiv 2021).